# Mock the CSS4 Subject Selector with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

### Introduction

So part of the specification for CSS4 is the [`subject` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject).

`E! > F`

This exciting selector syntax allows for styling of a parent element (`E!`) based on its child element (`F`). One example would be:

```
/* style the LI element */
ul > !li > p { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

In the case above, the LI element is styled, not the P element!

At the moment no browsers support this selector. What I am trying to do is create a jQuery plugin that

a) Checks if the browser supports this selector,

b) If not, then checks the CSS styles for a matching selector and

c) Implements the styling associated with the selector.

At the moment I can get my jQuery to read the CSS from a `<style>` tag on the page, but not from a `<link>`ed stylesheet.

### Question

How do I get jQuery to read all selectors for all loaded styles?

What is the best way to test if a browser supports this selector? I am thinking of creating a hidden element, adding a style to the page, and testing the css of the parent. Something like this (but more efficient):

```
//Create elements
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'selectorTester',
}).appendTo('body');
jQuery('<p/>', {
    id: 'selectorTesterP',
}).appendTo('#selectorTester');
jQuery('<style/>', {
    id: 'selectorTesterStyle',
    text: 'div#selectorTester! > p#selectorTesterP {color:red;}'
}).appendTo('body');
//Test if div has the correct style
if(jQuery('div#selectorTester').css('color') !== 'red') {
    // rest of script
}
```

Comment: Jumping the gun a bit aren't we? Anyway, doesn't JQ support a "parent" selector already?

Comment: Isn't this the same as `:has()`?

Comment: @Paulie_D - Yes, it does. And it is being put into CSS. It would be nice to use this cool feature now on browsers that don't support it. I'm ten years time (or whenever CSS4 begins getting implemented) this plugin will die a slow death and will eventually not be needed.

Comment: FWIW, the CSSWG just began polling folks on whether the subject indicator should be changed (again!) from `!` to `^`, or changed into a `:has()` pseudo-class a la jQuery instead: https://twitter.com/marcosc/status/433550868797878273 - you don't know for sure if the subject indicator is going to be changed into a pseudo-class, let alone remain as `!` as is currently proposed or changed into `^` (*or something else*). That's what @Paulie_D means by jumping the gun. You are very much better off waiting for the spec to stabilize before trying to implement such a major language feature.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - That is the jQuery implementation, but yes. I imagine when this is implemented in browsers, jQuery will have that feature do what I'm doing - test if the browser supports it, if so then use the browser selector, and if not does what it usually does. This is just my guess.

Comment: Oh and you don't know if it's even going to be part of CSS. It will *probably* finally make it into the Selectors 4 spec (after what 16 years of being thrown about?), but even then [it's slated to be excluded from CSS still](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#profiles). If you intend to use your plugin to polyfill the subject selector into CSS, you might wind up having to support it for a good long while.

Comment: @BoltClock - Interesting, but I'm not into jquery. Would `a:has(> img) span` match a `<span>` that's the descendent of an `<a>` which also has a `<img>` child? If so, that would be a massive extension to the selector language over a straight subject selector.

Comment: @Alohci jQuery already do this, but it is heavy to process : http://jsfiddle.net/4L2NK/2/

Comment: @Alohci: Yes. But it's also somewhat implied that `:matches()` will accept the subject selector in the complete profile, making the equivalent selector `a:matches(! > img) span` or similar.

Comment: @Alohci I imagine that would be how it would work. I an interested in the possibility of nested :has() selectors - `div:has(p:has(a.class))`

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King If we go back to your question, you are trying to implement exactly the same thing that `:has()` do? Nested has also work : http://jsfiddle.net/4L2NK/3/

Comment: OK, ignore implementing it for CSS4, however can my questions still be answered? I would still like to know out of personal interest. How do I read loaded stylesheets (without downloading them again), then read the selectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works on `<link>`ed stylesheets, but not on on-page `<style>` scripts.

```
//get loaded stylesheets
var x, sheets,classes;
for( sheets=document.styleSheets.length-1; sheets>=0; sheets-- ){
  classes = document.styleSheets[sheets].rules || document.styleSheets[sheets].cssRules;

  //check each rule for css4 selector
  for(x=0;x<classes.length;x++) {
    if(classes[x].selectorText.indexOf(':has(' > -1)) {
      //execute code here
    }
  }
}
```

This script assumes the new subject selector gets changed to `:has()`.